# Find the probability that no rock noise will be recorded for at least $30$ minutes.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

> Rock noise in an underground mine occurs at an average rate of three per hour. Find the probability that no rock noise will be recorded for at least 30 minutes.

I was able to get the density function for it as 
$f(x)=3e^{-3x}.$$ How do I get the probability?

Is this a Poisson Distribution or Exponential?

Comment: Integrate. More simply, you could have worked just with the Poisson distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas is this the one i need to find? P[X>=1/2]

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: As to your question about Poisson versus exponential, the Poisson would be used to model the **number** of events in given time. The exponential would model the waiting time for an event. Either can be used to find a correct solution  to the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you are dealing with a [_Poisson process_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process). It turns out the you can consider the problem with respect to time _or_ the number of arrivals. There are many more details. It turns out that there is a particular relationship regarding the first arrival I detailed in my answer.

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest any distributional assumption whatsoever. All that is provided is an average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the average is $3$ per hour, then the time to the first arrival has density
$$f_X(x) = 3\exp\left\{-3x\right\}.$$

Further, the question asks $P(X> 30\text{ min}) = P(X> .5\text{ hr})$. Compute this using the usually integration.

***Warning!***

This is correct if you logic is that the time to the first arrival follows an exponential distribution. Otherwise, recognize that you are dealing with a Poisson distribution.

In other words,

$$A = \{\text{First arrival after 30 mins}\}\iff B =\{\text{Number of arrivals in 30 mins is zero}\}.$$

Hence
$$P(A) = P(B) = e^{-\mu t}\frac{\mu^0}{0!} = e^{-3(.5)} = e^{-1.5}=0.2231302.$$

Comment: Why is it Exponential or Poisson? There is nothing in the question to suggest any distributional assumption whatsoever. All that is provided is an average.

Comment: @wolfies Yeah, you're justified in your concern...... but it's an exercise. Most likely from a section called Poisson distribution or Exponential distribution or the like. We have to assume, otherwise it is not solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 1.5$ for a half hour period.

Then, it's just  $P(0) = e^{-1.5}$

Comment: Is this a Poisson distribution ?

Comment: The exponential distribution and the Poisson distribution are closely related, and one can often use the simpler of the two, as we can here. You can read about the relationship between them in more detail on many answers on this site.